# Checking if Component has a Text Property

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I check if the component has a text property. As I read Rtti will be a good soulution but I did not worked with it before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function HasTextProp(aControl: TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if (aComponent is ?) then
     Exit(True);
end;

var
  ObjList: TObjectList<TControl>;
  ObjIdx: Integer;
begin
   ObjList := TObjectList<TControl>.Create,
   ObjList.Add(comp1); {is TcxButton}
   ObjList.Add(comp2); {is Tedit}
   ObjList.Add(comp3); {is TDateTimeEdit}

  for ObjIdx := 0 to lObjList.Count -1 do
  begin
    if HasTextProp(lObjList.Items[ObjIdx]) then
      do something...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What have you tried with RTTI?

Comment: FWIW TControl *has* a Text property, its just protected. So I guess you want to know if the concrete class that inherits from TControl has made it public or published.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For example for **published** properties:

```
uses
  System.TypInfo;

function HasTextProp(AControl: TControl): Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsPublishedProp(AControl, 'Text');
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Victroia! That is what Im looking for. And what if I want to check it's value? If it is empty or not.

Comment: Assuming `Text` will be a string property, you could use `GetStrProp(AControl, 'Text') <> ''`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Victoria!

Answer (score 7):

Victoria showed you how to accomplish your goal using old-style RTTI, which works only with published properties and nothing else.  In Delphi 2010 and later, there is a new-style RTTI that works with almost everything (private/protected/public/published, properties, data members, etc), and can also accomplish your goal, eg:

```
uses
  ..., System.TypInfo, System.Rtti;

function HasTextProp(aControl: TControl): Boolean;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  Prop := Ctx.GetType(aControl.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
  Result := (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]);
end;
```

`TRttiProperty` has `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods, eg:

```
var
  Ctrl: TControl
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  ...
  Ctrl := lObjList.Items[ObjIdx];
  Prop := Ctx.GetType(Ctrl.ClassType).GetProperty('Text');
  if (Prop <> nil) and (Prop.Visibility in [mvPublic, mvPublished]) then
  begin
    if Prop.GetValue(Ctrl).IsEmpty then
      Prop.SetValue(Ctrl, 'Not Empty Anymore!');
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was useful.

Comment: Can confirm this works well! Only this was a bit too much of code for my minor issue in `TEdit` and `TComboBox` controls, in which I liked to read and write their `.SelStart` and some other properties.